# Значення слова розписка

Tags: значення-слів

Кілька разів чула, що слово "розписка" (з наголосом на О) вживають у значенні укладання шлюбу.

В мережі знайшла лише про розпИску, [зокрема у Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0):

> Розписка — це документ, який підтверджує передачу й одержання грошей, матеріальних цінностей, документів тощо від установи чи приватної особи.

Можливо, рОзписка - діалектне похідне від російського "роспись"? Взагалі існує таке слово?

Comment: я думаю, варто уточнити, де саме ви чули це вживання з наголосом на першому складі.

Answer (score 2):

Гадаю йшлося про звичайну [розпИску](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0). І ["Словник української мови" в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozpyska), і [стаття "Форморозрізнювальна роль наголосу в іменниках першої відміни" В. Винницького](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine6-9.pdf) (ст. 2) пишуть, що наголос на букву "И" (і це вірний варіант).

Однак, натрапив на [статтю "Наголошування префіксально-суфіксальних іменників жіночого роду з суфіксом -к(а)" В. Винницького](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/110454/31-Vinnytskyi.pdf?sequence=1) (на жаль не вдається скопіювати), де подається як варіант "рОзписка", так і "розпИска". Можливо, ви почули "рОзписка" у якомусь регіоні, де зберігся наголос на префікс, однак слово означає те саме, що і "розпИска". І так, в російській мові існує слово "[роспись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)".

Comment: Так, підтримую цю відповідь. Згідно з 2-ю наведеною статтею В. Винницького, в таких словах «здавна… діє тенденція до переміщення наголосу з префікса на корінь», і в словнику Грінченка (1909) ми ще бачимо старий наголос [рОсписка](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=росписка&dicts=12). Ймовірно, просто десь досі використовується старий наголос (хоч і нормою він уже не вважається).